# How to avoid DRY code with React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component, material-ui

Currently Using React with Material UI v1.0 in implementing a list but I don't want to repeat my code.

The existing Code looks like this.

```js
import List from 'material-ui/List';
import DashboardIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Dashboard';
import BuildIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Build';
import Listings from './BarComponents';


function SideBar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <List>
          <ListItem button>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <DashboardIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />
        </ListItem>

        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemIcon>
            <BuildIcon />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary="Control Panel" />
        </ListItem> 
      </List>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SideBar;
```

I want to get avoid repeating creating the list items so i've created a new file and passed the props into, code is below.

```
import React from 'react'
import  { ListItem, ListItemIcon, ListItemText } from 'material-ui/List';

export default function Listings(props) {
  return(
    <div>
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <props.icon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={props.prim} />
      </ListItem>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And also this

```
    <Listings icon={DashboardIcon} prim="Dashboard" />
    <Listings icon={BuildIcon} prim="Build" />
```

Into the original file for a replacement of

```
    <ListItem button>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <DashboardIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />
    </ListItem>

    <ListItem button>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <BuildIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
   <ListItemText primary="Control Panel" />
  </ListItem>
```

Is the best way to pass a component e.g  though
 and call it via  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note: "DRY code" usually refers to non-repeated, well thought out code

Comment: Just use a loop, and store the data for each component in a prop array. Here's a good example how it is done: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: To avoid DRY code, copy and paste. Lots.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a dynamic component.

```
renderElement(name, props = {}) {
  var MyComponent = name
  return <MyComponent {...props} />;
}

render() {

    return(
    <div>
        <ListItem v-for="item in list" key={item.id} button={item.button}>
            <ListItemIcon>
                {renderElement(props.icon)}
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={props.prim} />
        </ListItem>
    </div>
  );

}
```